# Font isn't consistent on the old devices and platforms, and design elements break sometimes

Tags: html, css, email, signature

I'm trying to unify the font to appear the same on all operating systems and devices. Also some design elements break on different devices. what am I doing wrong? this is my code below?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="768">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100" width="250">
        <img src="https://www.westcoastelevators.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/West-Coast-Elevators-Email-Signature-Image.jpg" alt="west coast elevators logo" width="350px" height="150" style=" margin-top: 28px">

        </td>
      <td colspan="4" height="20" width="200px"><p style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom: 5px; line-height: 20px; font-family: 'sans-serif', 'lato';"><strong>Full Name</strong><br>
    <span style="font-size: 15px; font-family: 'sans-serif', 'lato'; color: #000000;">Managing Director</span></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10px" width="200px">
      <td colspan="1" width="120px"><p style="margin-bottom: -0px; font-size: 15px"><a href="tel:0430000000" style="text-decoration: none;color: black; font-family: 'sans-serif', 'lato';">0000 000 000</a></p></td>
      <td colspan="2" width="80px"><p style="margin-bottom: -0px;font-size: 15px"><a href="tel:0000000000" style="text-decoration: none; color: black; font-family: 'sans-serif', 'lato';">08 6263 5253</a></p></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td height="47" colspan="3" width="220px"><p style="line-height: 0px; margin-top: 0px; font-family: 'sans-serif', 'lato';font-size: 15px"><a href="https://goo.gl/maps/G5qdX7BeFz6HY7Rv6" style="text-decoration: none;color: black">20 Wynyard St, Belmont WA 6104</a></p>
      <p style="text-decoration: none; line-height: 10px; font-family: 'sans-serif', 'lato'; font-size: 15px"><a href="westcoastelevators.com.au" style="text-decoration: none;color: black; font-weight: bold;">westcoastelevators.com.au </a></p></td>
    <td width="180" ><a href="https://www.facebook.com/westcoastelevatorsperth/"><img style="margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 10px" src="https://www.westcoastelevators.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Artboard-3.png" alt="facebook logo"></a> <a href="http://www.instagram.com/westcoast_elevators/"><img style="margin-top: 10px" src="https://www.westcoastelevators.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Artboard-4.png" alt="instagram logo"></a></td></tr>


    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: First of all, there is a big difference between `'sans-serif'` and `sans-serif`. Secondly, not all platforms have the `'Lato'` font, and what is used for `sans-serif` depends on the user settings. If you want to be sure the same font is used on all platforms, the only choice is a webfont.

Comment: So do you think the solution would be to adjust the font-family tags to font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif.  Then add a link in the header to <style> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap');</style>

Comment: Yes. But I'm not sure what you mean with "design elements break". Can you give an example?

Comment: I have included social logos at the end, they just keep going on top of each other when its viewed on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tool for cross-browser/platform font issue: https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/ try to download font from here and then import it in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

To make the font constant everywhere, you would have to use a web font as Mr. Lister has said.
You could get fonts from all over the internet, but for now, getting fonts from [here](https://fonts.google.com) would be best.

An example, after selecting your font, you would import it into your HTML or CSS.
For HTML:

```
<body>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</body>
```

or

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap');
</style>
```

For CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap');
```

Then to use it in your code (Note: This is how I would do it, after seeing what you are trying to do in your code):

```
<style>
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap");

  .p {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  }
  <!-- You will have to remove the font-family styling from all the tags though then leave this style tag in. -->
</style>
```

However, I strongly advise you look into external CSS. It would make your code much easier to work with.